Do electricity meters calculate electricity usage accurately?
I want to ask a question about electricity meters. The amount of current in the cables coming from the network to the house and distributed to the sockets is determined by the resistance and is fixed. But since each device has a different resistance, it has different current values ​​and the power it consumes is different. Since the meters that count electricity use calculate according to the current passing through them, do they calculate more than the electrical energy actually consumed?

the amount of current coming in is most certainly NOT fixed (though it is limited), it varies by the load in the house; all parts of a series circuit have the same current.

Why would they calculate more than consumed? They should be as accurate as stated or required. What are you after with this question? They will see the sum of current from all individual loads.

@Justme When the current decreases according to the resistance of the device, does the current in the cable connected to the socket also decrease? I did not understand this part.

@Ahmet The current in the main cable that the meter measures is the sum of all of the currents downstream of the meter at any given time, no matter how the loads are varying.

@Justme How can it calculate the sum of all currents? Shouldn't it just calculate the current passing through it?

@Ahmet The sum of all load currents is the current passing through it.

@Hearth Are you talking about the current returning from the neutral? If the current passing through the cable is different from the current on the device according to its resistance, how does it calculate the sum of the currents?

Current flows in a closed loop - anything flowing through any of the devices in your home must come in from the service and flow back out through the service. This means it must also flow through the meter as that is inline with the supply. Regardless of how many devices you have and what their individual currents are, it all flows in totality through the meter and is thus measured correctly. The meter can't tell you how much each individual device is using, just the total amount.

@Ahmet The current passing through the hot is always equal to the current returning through the neutral (as long as there isn't a ground fault, anyway).

The amount of current passing through the phase and neutral is the same, yes, but this is the amount of current sent to the devices. The individual currents of the devices decrease according to the resistance. When we take into account the resistance in the devices, wouldn't the voltage x current spent and the current x voltage passing through the cable be different? I tried to ask this. @Hearth

Hi @Ahmet, check out https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-6/kirchhoffs-current-law-kcl/

@Ahmet No. The current through the cable is exactly the same as the total of the current through the devices. It's just like if you have a car with a top speed of 200 kph, you can still drive it at 100 kph--it's not always operating at the maximum.

@Ahmet At least, I think I understand where you're confused. But if that doesn't clear anything up, please try to clarify what you mean by "sent to the devices" and "voltage x current spent".

The water analogy is an excellent model for current conservation. Imagine you have a big water pipe coming into your house, through a water meter. As you turn taps on and off, use the shower, it registers the total amount of water flowing in, and used by your appliances. Current and charge behave exactly the same way as flow rate and total volume. The water model is of course a lousy analogy for how electricity actually works, but like all models, it's good and bad for different things, and it's really good for current and charge.

Thanks for all your answers but I want to ask this lastly; A device that works with high wattage draws more current than a device that works with low wattage. Therefore, the electrical energy they consume is different. It should be reflected differently on the bill. But I don't understand how the current increases and decreases in the cable between the fuse and the socket. Shouldn't the current be constant in that cable? If it doesn't increase or decrease, then shouldn't all devices connected to a socket with a voltage x current consume the same electrical energy in a certain period of time?

@Hearth Let's say there is a device that consumes high wattage and the current flows faster in its cables, how does this reflect on the phase cable between the fuse and the socket? If the current there is constant, how does the device with the faster current draw more current?

@Ahmet this site is not a chat forum ... please ask your questions in the question section, not in the comment section

there is no faster current draw ... there is higher current draw


A device that works with high wattage draws more current than a device that works with low wattage. Therefore, the electrical energy they consume is different. It should be reflected differently on the bill. But I don't understand how the current increases and decreases in the cable between the fuse and the socket. Shouldn't the current be constant in that cable?


Let's say there is a device that consumes high wattage and the current flows faster in its cables, how does this reflect on the phase cable between the fuse and the socket? If the current there is constant, how does the device with the faster current draw more current?

I think your confusion might be resolved by one diagram:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Load A requires 1 A, load B requires 3 A, but all the meter sees is the combined total of 4 A.
This is an application of Kirchoff's current law, which may be a search term to look up if you're unfamiliar.

The current is the same on meter and loads (plus any possible leakage paths between live and neutral).
However, as wires have resistance, the voltage may drop in the wires before reaching load. So power entering wire at say 230V 1A is only 229V 1A at device due to losses in wiring, contact resistance, breakers/fuses etc.
But those losses are small, and your devices have losses too that make them heat due to inefficies.
The point is the meter measures what enters your house/apartment and everything behind it, including minimal losses that happens in breakers and wirings too.
What happens after the meter is up to you how old or how well-designed wiring you have. For example if your lights dim a bit when a fridge or heater starts to run, it means that the lamp also experiences voltage drop when a high current load starts. If the voltage drop happens before the meter then the meter should compensate for voltage at the meter.

For those of us in a cold climate, that extra volt lost in the cable heats my house anyway so I do get some use out of it!

Let's get this out of the way first: Current from the utility isn't 'constant'. Instead, current varies with load. It is the voltage that is more or less constant.
The meter measures total current to a household. To do this, the utility phases connect the meter, through the meter, then on to power busses in the panel. Form there all of the house branch circuits connect to the panel common busses.
Connected this way, the meter sees all the current in and out of the house. It also measures each phase voltage. Using that information it calculates power accurately, regardless of variation in load or any resistive (IR drop) losses that might be present in the wiring.
Here's a diagram showing the scheme for a North American style 120/240V system:

From here: https://heatzone.ca/project-view/basics-of-homes-electrical-system/
Since all the utility feeds go through the meter, none of the current in or out escapes the meter's notice. It also measures voltage, and additionally compensates for any non-ideal power factor.
Connected this way, the meter has all it needs to accurately compute total instantaneous power regardless of variable load. It then tallies (integrates) power over time to give energy consumed, which is recorded in the meter and used for billing.
More here: Why is electricity consumption billed in watts and not amperes?
Back to the diagram for a moment. If you had 2A/120V on the upper plug, and 2A/240V on the lower plug. Meter aggregate the three currents, which work out to 240 + 480W = 720W total.
Run it that way for 1 hour, and you've consumed 720 watt-hours (0.72 kWh) which would show up on the meter.
So what about the IR drops that waste power, such as in the wiring, breakers, and plug contacts? These don't escape the meter: they're resistances in series with their loads, each with its own voltage (IR) drop that causes heat. The heat is the ‘wasted’ energy, or power loss.
The result is that these IR drops cause the load to get a little less voltage, and thus, power. Nevertheless, IR drop power losses are still power consumed as far as the meter is concerned. They're faithfully tallied in the meter along with the intended loads.
How much loss? Allowable IR drop from panel to plug is 3 to 5% of the line voltage. Any more than that is considered excessive, not compliant to electrical code, and should be checked by a qualified electrician.
